# How to set container height that will increase according to expands: true, textfield

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using listView then i have container that contain TextField with `expands: true,` `maxLines: null,` if I don't set the container height it will error if set the height and if the textfield have a lot of words the container height won't increase/expand what I want to achieve is the container height increase as the textfield words/content.

Note: the border is temporary, it's just for you to be able to see which container

here's the picture of the textfield

[image]

and here is the code

```
ListView(
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 0, 24, 0),
              height: height * 0.15,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              child: Focus(
                onFocusChange: (focus) {
                  onFocusChange();
                },
                child: TextField(
                  controller: textNote,
                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                  expands: true,
                  maxLines: null,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    saveNote();
                  },
                  onEditingComplete: () {
                    saveNote();
                    removeFocus();
                  },
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.85),
                    fontSize: 26,
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Haha the answer is simple, just put `maxLines: null` `expands: false` and the parent container didn't need height